# Change the smoothness on a volcano plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have produced a volcano plot, however the underlying data has gaps, i.e. the histogram data looks like:

[image]

When I produce the volcano plot it looks a bit silly:

[image]

Is it possible to apply a smoother to the shaded area to iron out the ribbed feature; surely, it must already have a smoothness associated with it, otherwise the shadow would drop back to 0 each time?

Code:

```
ggplot(fly2[fly2$Region == "different",], aes(x = Probability)) +
 stat_density(aes(ymax = ..density..,  ymin = -..density..),
 fill = "grey50", colour = "grey50",
 geom = "ribbon", position = "identity") +
 facet_grid(. ~ Algorithm) + xlim(0,0.3) +
 coord_flip()
```

link to the dput file:

```
 http://pastebin.com/ba95WEab
```

Comment: It would be easier if you'd provide a `dput` of your data and the code you've used

Comment: Is that okay? Never really used dput before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `adjust` in `geom_density`.

For example, when I use `adjust = 1.6`, this is what I get

```
ggplot(fly2[fly2$Region == "different",], aes(x = Probability)) +
  stat_density(aes(ymax = ..density..,  ymin = -..density..),
               fill = "grey50", colour = "grey50",
               geom = "ribbon", position = "identity",
               adjust=1.6) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Algorithm) + xlim(0,0.3) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: You're a star! It seems so obvious now, i'm surprised no one got there before you!